# How can I call a function in a child controller in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

In my code I have the following:

```
<html data-ng-controller="appController"
      data-ng-keydown="callFunction($event)">
```

In the single page application I open a page and it has a `detailController` with the following:

```
    $scope.callFunction = function (eventNew) {
        var a = 0;
        if (eventNew.which == 39)
            alert('Right arrow key pressed');
    }
```

But this function is not getting called. The only time it is called is
if the function is coded in the appController.

How can I call that function in my `detailController` controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of directly invoking the method, you can `$broadcast` a keydown event down to child scopes and handle key down event.

```
<html data-ng-controller="appController"
      data-ng-keydown="$broadcast('keydown',$event)">

 $scope.$on('keydown', function(event, args) {
    $window.alert('key was down ' + args.which)
  })
```

Comment: It seems like the event is not being populated when it is on the HTML. Can you confirm this?

Comment: It does work on HTML tag. $broadcast is a method on scope so make sure your controller is also defined on HTML.

Comment: actually the event object passed from broadcast corresponds to the second argument of the event handler. Updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

You can't because the parent controller (app) does not have access to your child controller's scope. If you want to define your callFunction on detailController's scope then you have to call it from the detail controller.

```
<html data-ng-controller="appController" >
    <body ng-controller="detailController" data-ng-keydown="callFunction($event)">
    </body>
</html>
```